# Slice, trim the string from a specific character

Tags: javascript

```
var text = ~/Desktop/Bon/ai2html-output/home-pro-Artboard_1.jpg
```

In js how would I get the final file name.  Basically getting any string after the last '/'.  It will always change.

Comment: Use `split()` to split the string into an array, then get the last element of the array.

Comment: text.split(“/“).pop()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var text = '~/Desktop/Bon/ai2html-output/home-pro-Artboard_1.jpg';
var filename = text.replace(/^.*\//, ''); // 'home-pro-Artboard_1.jpg'
```

Explanation of regex:

- `/^.*\//`: greedily remove all leading text up to and including the last slash